# How can I check URL content with Cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I want to check my URL content and do something like this:

```js
if (URL.include('path')) {
  //do something 
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

I can check my URL like this

```js
cy.url().should('include', 'path');
```

but when I am pasting it in `if` operator it is not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Will recommend you to use `.includes()` method. It determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string:

```
const path = 'user/survey';

cy.url().then(($url) => {
    if($url.includes(path)) {
        cy.log("Yes")
    } else  {
        cy.log("No")
      }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine [location()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location.html)  with [then()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html).

Here is how I do it:

```
    cy.location('pathname').then((loc) => {
        if(loc == '/my/path') {
            ...do
        } else {
           ...smth else
        } 
    })
```

I hope it solves your issue,
Best

Comment: Thanks for answer. when I print LOC, it result is 
Object{14}  and always doing ELSE field

Comment: @François: `loc == '/my/path'` may not be true in case of a partial search. it should be `loc.includes('/my/path')`

Comment: @Sree.Bh True, In my use case I was checking the login page so no need "includes", but your answer is more general!

Answer (score 2):

I found The answer, but its vary long. Any ideas pls.

```
      cy.url().then(url => {
         const currentURL = url.split('/path/');
         const pathURL = currentURL[1];
         if(pathURL === 'user/survey')
         {
            cy.log('aaaaaaaaaa')
         } else {
            cy.log('bbbbbbbbb')
         }
     })
```